# Simple way to filter groups with all values matching a condition in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data with the following structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS tbl (
  id int,
  value int
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 0),
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(2, 1);
```

What's the simplest way to filter ids where all the values of `value` are positive in BigQuery?

In this case, we would only keep `id = 2` since `id = 1` has a value which is 0.

Is there an `all_values` or something similar that I can use to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may aggregate and then assert a boolean expression for the sum of positive numbers:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(value > 0) = COUNT(*);
```

If you want to retain the original records, then use:

```sql
SELECT id, value
FROM tbl
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl GROUP BY id HAVING SUM(value > 0) = COUNT(*));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use aggregation and having, but phrase the filtering like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(value) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, below is the most scalable approach

```
select * from tbl
where true
qualify countif(value <= 0) over(partition by id) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```sql
select id 
from tbl
group by id
having(countif(value > 0) = count(*))
```

I'm not sure this is the simplest or most performant though.